# HBase: HMaster and HRegionServer is automatically stop some hour later after starting

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I got odd situations about HBase. I can start HBase and create table etc first few hours.
But, some hours later HMaster and HRegionServer is stopped.

Environment
Hadoop 2.6.4 (Preudodistributed Mode)
HBase 1.1.5 (Preudodistributed Mode)

I check the logs.
This is HMaster logs which I think have connection with the problem.

```
2016-07-27 17:20:01,762 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-07-27 17:47:59,091 WARN  [192.168.11.2,16000,1469607706691_ChoreService_1] cleaner.CleanerChore: Error while cleaning the logs
java.net.ConnectException: Call From hatanokaoruakira-no-MacBook-Air.local/192.168.11.2 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2016-07-27 17:48:02,029 WARN  [LeaseRenewer:Kuma@localhost] hdfs.LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_374187999_1] for 30 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...
java.net.ConnectException: Call From hatanokaoruakira-no-MacBook-Air.local/192.168.11.2 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

This is HRegionServer logs.

```
2016-07-27 19:32:14,848 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-07-27 19:32:14,960 WARN  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
```

This is Zookeerper logs.

```
2016-07-27 18:50:54,129 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1562b9e5e9b0007, likely client has closed socket
2016-07-27 18:50:54,131 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53248 which had sessionid 0x1562b9e5e9b0007
2016-07-27 18:52:24,004 INFO  [SessionTracker] server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1562b9e5e9b0007, timeout of 90000ms exceeded
2016-07-27 18:52:24,007 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1562b9e5e9b0007
2016-07-27 19:31:27,585 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53956
2016-07-27 19:31:27,593 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53956
2016-07-27 19:31:27,598 INFO  [SyncThread:0] server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1562b9e5e9b0008 with negotiated timeout 90000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53956
2016-07-27 19:31:28,943 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1562b9e5e9b0008, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-27 19:31:28,945 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53956 which had sessionid 0x1562b9e5e9b0008
```

And this is my hbase-site.xml.
[image]

If anyone have advise, please tell me.
Thank you.